# How to change how long items are kept in the trash?

Tags: wp-admin, hooks, wp-config, configuration

When the trash feature is enabled, the deleted posts are moved to trash and stored there for 30 days. And there is a schedule/wp_cron event that is responsible for removing these posts permanently after that time.

Is there any easy way to change that time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change that in `wp-config` (https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Empty_Trash):

```
define( 'EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS', 1 ); // Integer is the amount of days
```

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Empty_Trash